# Android Studio Application

Tags: android

I'm working on a project in Android Studio and I am using my Samsung Galaxy phone to test my application after every project modification. 
My problem is that after I use one time my phone or the emulator to test the application, then I cannot run it again on the same device.

When I try it, the application don't show any errors, but the screen that appears on the phone or emulator is blank. 
I tried to remake the project but after first try the phone and emulator showed the same problem.

How can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: The information is too generic. It could be anything, can you provide a little more specific information?

Comment: Hey! Sure! The idea is that after first run of every new emulator the application appears blank and i tried to remake in another project. After first run, result was the same. Next i started to comment on paths every activities, result - same. In Logcat: Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket' OR in first project Logcat shows system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module.

Comment: can you post your logcat?